# A little utility bar on the top of the main Navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a main navbar with a scroll animation on my website. I wanted to created a fixed, little (and nontransparent) utility bar that would always stay on the top of my site.

**This is what I have now:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrXgw.jpg

**And this is what happens when I add the utility bar to it:**

[image: Utility]

I've tried multiple stuff and I have no idea how to fix this.

**This is my utility navbar code:**

```
export const UtilityNav = styled.nav`   
  background: yellow;   
  position: sticky;   
  min-height: 40px;   
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */  
  /* margin-top: 20px; */  
  /* margin-top: -10px; */   
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;  
  align-items: center; 
  font-size: 1rem; 
  top: 0; 
  z-index: 10;
`;
```

**And this is my main Navbar code:**

```
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: ${({ scrollNav }) => (scrollNav ? '#81A687' : 'transparent')};
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: 0.8s all ease;

  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    transition: 0.8s all ease;
  }
`;
```

The negative **margin-top: -80px** makes the navbar transparent before scrolling down. I think this is something I need to work on, but the most logical (at least for me) change to **margin-top: -110px;** (NavBar height + UtilityBar height) didn't work... :-(
I have no other ideas. I'm looking for the easiest way, I'm completely new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this adding UtilityBar to my main Navbar and displayed them in the same flex container with height of 110px.

```
<Nav scrollNav={scrollNav}><UtilityNav>[...]</UtilityNav></Nav>
```

This way the whole bar sticks to the top. I still have no idea why they didn't stick to each other as seperate components, but this workaround works great for now.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried creating a parent container to both of them, so the sticky position would work, but everything well apart when I did.

Judging by this statement, these navs in different parents, I've made a simple demo, basically, if you can't have a single parent for these navs, you must at least have them inside `relative` containers, this way they will not overlap.

If you change `.container` style to `fixed` or `absolute` positioning in the demo, you will have the same bug as you have

https://jsfiddle.net/DraGonM/yjqtms05/20/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've edited my post because I realised that they were in the same parent container before (I still have problems understanding basic stuff). Now they are seperate components but put together into the same parent, home container. I still cant figure out how to stop the overlapping.
If I put any of them in a position different than sticky, they don't stay on the top of the website. :-(

Comment: In that case, we need to know parent styles because if both children have a `sticky` position usually they will not overlap.

Comment: This is my home App.css:

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Cairo',
    sans-serif;
}

Comment: @kwi these styles not adding this bug, https://jsfiddle.net/DraGonM/yjqtms05/27/

are you sure this is the only parent of these navs?
you can also check parents in HTML by right-clicking on the element and select `inspect`